# Django ORM to get a nested tree of models from DB with minimal SQL queries

Tags: django-models, django-orm

I have some nested models with foreign key relationships going 4 levels deep.

A <- B <- C <- D

A has a set of B models, which each have a set of C models, which each have a set of D models.

I'm iterating of the each model (4 layers of looping from A down to B).  This is producing lots of DB hits.

I don't need to do any filtering at the DB fetch level, as I need all the data from all the DB tables, so I ideally I'd like to get all the data with ONE SQL query that hits the DB (if that's possible) and then somehow have the data organized/filtered into their correct sets for each model.  i.e. it's all pre-fetched and structured ready for using the data (e.g. in a web dashboard).

There seems to be a lot of django related pre-fetch helpers and packages, but none of them seem to work the way I expect.  e.g. `django-auto-prefetch` (which seems ideal).

Is this a common use case (I thought it would be)?

How can I construct the ORM to get all the data in one hit and then just use the bits I need.

**NOTE:** target system is raspberry pi class device (1GHz Arm processor) with eMMC storage (similar to SD card), and using SQLite as the DB backend.

**NOTE:** I'm also using this with `django-polymorphic`, which may or may not make a difference?

Thanks, Brendan.

Comment: Using one query would result in a huge amount of bandwidth, since the values for the columns of the A model will be repeated per B model per C model per D model. Therefore `.prefetch_related` makes two extra queries *per* level at most, so seven queries in total, which will minimize the bandwidth.

Comment: Have a quick look at [MPTT](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Using one query would result in a huge amount of bandwidth, since the values for the columns of the A model will be repeated per B model per C model per D model.

Indeed, the response would look like:

```
a_col1 | a_col2 | b_col1 | b_col2 | c_col1 | d_col1
  A1       A1       B1       B1        C1      D1
  A1       A1       B1       B1        C1      D2
  A1       A1       B1       B1        C1      D3
  A1       A1       B1       B1        C2      D4
  A1       A1       B1       B1        C2      D5
  A1       A1       B1       B1        C2      D6
  A1       A1       B2       B2        C3      D7
  A1       A1       B2       B2        C3      D8
  A1       A1       B2       B2        C3      D9
  A1       A1       B2       B2        C4      D10
  A1       A1       B2       B2        C4      D11
  A1       A1       B2       B2        C4      D12
  A2       A2       B3       B3        C5      D13
  A2       A2       B3       B3        C5      D14
  A2       A2       B3       B3        C5      D15
  A2       A2       B3       B3        C5      D16
```

We thus would repeat the values for the `a_column`s, `b_column`s, etc. a large number of times resulting in a large amount of bandwidth going from the database to the Python/Django layer. This would not only result in large amounts of data being transferred, but also large amounts of memory being used by Django to deserialize this response.

Therefore `.prefetch_related` makes one (or two depending on the type of relation) extra queries *per* level at most, so three to seven queries in total, which will minimize the bandwidth.

You thus can fetch all objects in memory with:

```
for a in A.objects.prefetch_related('b_set', 'b_set__c_set', , 'b_set__c_set__d_set'):
    print(a)
    for b in a.b_set.all():
        print(b)
        for c in b.c_set.all():
            print(c)
            for d in c.d_set.all():
                print(d)
```

Comment: I have experimented with `prefetch_related()` and did get some improvements but felt the optimization could be better.  Would it be more efficient to read all the rows of each table (e.g. 4 SQL hits, or maybe less), possibly into dicts with `__dict__` or `model_to_dict()` and then stitch the relationships together manually?  Is there some facility or external module to do that already?

Comment: @BrendanSimon: for small dataset's it is indeed not a good idea. But for larger datasets, using a single query will likely let the application crash due to memory problems. Since it means that all columns are repeated a large amount of times. Especially since Python is not very memory efficient, that would make the application non-responsive.

Comment: @BrendanSimon: in fact `prefetch_related` exactly *does* that: it loads the rows with four queries (if these are `ForeignKey`s in reverse), and then stitches it manually.

Comment: Yes, that's what I read but in my app I'm getting a lot more hits than I expect (gut feel) - using django-debug-toolbar.  I think I will need to pare it down to a simple examples and profile it and present the actual code.

Comment: Just to clarify, if I read all rows from all tables (4), *without* prefetch (i.e. lazy), then I would get 4 hits without repeating data (and I would have the foreign ids).  I could then stitch together for the hierarchy of model sets.  I don't think standard prefetch_related works this way, as each of the model sets are a different query and don't benefit from the caching of other similar prefetches.  Is that correct?  i.e. so standard prefetch_related has many more DB hits (much greater than 4) - correct?